LeafletJS: Mouse click event on a LayerGroup not working
I added a click event to a LayerGroup. But it did not work.
I am pasting code below:
const map1 = L.map("map1", {
    center: [11.274, 50.765].reverse(),
    zoom: 10
    });

const mlyr2 = L.layerGroup([
    L.marker([11.274, 50.765].reverse()),
    L.marker([13.537, 49.877].reverse()),
  ]).addTo(map1);


mlyr2.on('click', function(e){
  alert("clicked the layergroup!");
});

The alert is not displayed.
Is it that mouse events don't work on layergroups
and that we should use featuregroup instead.
Further I am using the latest leaflet version

According to documentation your code should work, but it doesn't. I have no idea why it doesn't work, but there is a simple workaround. Just iterate all the layers of layer group:
mlyr2.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.on('click', function(e){
    alert("clicked the layergroup!");
  });
)};

If you don't like this solution, you'll have to use L.featureGroup, where it's clearly stated in the docs:

Events are propagated to the FeatureGroup, so if the group has an
event handler, it will handle events from any of the layers. This
includes mouse events and custom events.


Thanks, I wanted event handler to work on the group as a whole and FeatureGroup worked great.
